# Failed linux Kernel Firmware Update

Tags: installation, apt, updates, package-management, dpkg

Ok guys this is what I get

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      linux-firmware
    1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 23.1 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 23.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-firmware all 1.79.4 [23.1 MB]
    Fetched 23.1 MB in 1min 48s (213 kB/s)                                         
    (Reading database ... 367107 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb (--unpack):
    trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin', which is also in package amd64-microcode 1.20120910-1
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.4_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a ppa purge of amd-microcode ppa and remove amd-microcode via software center or sudo apt-get --purge remove, reboot and rerun the upgrade.